# Can paginate_links() be customized for a specific category or tag?

Tags: categories, filters, tags, paginate-links

I am creating category and tag page templates for my client so they can post news articles to the news category page and specific news pages separated by tag with a pagination nav at the bottom of each page. What I noticed, however, is the pagination nav takes account of all of the posts belonging to any category or having any tag.

I am aware that paginate_links() does not pass an argument in any way similar to the category_name argument for WP_Query(). Keeping this in mind, I spent Googling for a solution to excluding all of the irrelevant posts from the scope of paginate_links() with no luck.

Can you write paginate_links() so that the function targets a specific category or tag? If so, please help me work out how.

The below is the code including the query and pagination function:

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'category_name' => 'NEWS',
            'tag_slug__and' => $tags,
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
            <div class="inner">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'format'  => 'page/%#%',
                'current' => $paged,
                'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                'mid_size'        => 2,
                'prev_text'       => __('&laquo; Previous Page’),
                'next_text'       => __(‘Next Page &raquo;')
            ) );
        ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you for reading this.

Ead

Comment: You dont need to pass custom query to `paginate_links()`. Custom query will suffice I guess. See this example - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#comment-418

Comment: `paginate_links()` only paginate the query's results; you can use the `pre_get_posts` hook (particularly for the main query) to control the query arguments or make a custom `WP_Query` request where you have full control over the query arguments. So for example, you can do `new WP_Query( 'category_name=foo' )` and then call `paginate_links()`, and the pagination wouldn't "include" posts that are not in the `foo` category.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating these templates incorrectly. When you create categories they automatically get pages where you can view that category's posts. You just need to build your templates correctly. What do your templates look like?

Comment: Sally CJ's comment makes sense, but I seem to have paginate_links() inside the custom query already as follows:

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  endwhile;
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'format'  => 'page/%#%',
    'current' => $paged,
    'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'mid_size'        => 2,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo; Next Page'),
    'next_text'       => __('Previous Page&raquo;')
          ) );
endif;

Comment: Why are you doing `$the_query = new WP_Query($args);`? That should not be required in category templates.

Comment: I want to apply category.php to a number of category archive pages such as News, Brands and Events, hence including the custom query statement for the News archive. $args is set as follows:

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'category_name' => 'NEWS',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'paged' => $paged
);

Comment: @EadWig, what do you mean by "apply to a number of category archive pages"? The standard category archive template (`category.php`) is already being applied to any categories (terms in the `category` taxonomy) on the site - e.g. `/category/news` and `/category/brands`. Are you saying that you're making a `WP_Query` request for other categories in your category template? Or is "News" for example, a custom taxonomy's term?

Comment: @Sally CJ
I'm aware that category.php is applied to every category and planning to set a custom loop argument for each category in the same template file. The paginate_links() enabled pagination in the page successfully except for the filtering by category/tag...

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your `WP_Query` code? Or can we see your category template?

Comment: Included the code in my question.

Comment: Are you sure the category *slug* is `NEWS`? Because the `category_name` parameter is a slug, and slugs in WordPress are (by default) always in lowercase. But then, why would you query another category in a category archive?...

Comment: WP treats uppercase and lowercase category slugs the same. Replacing NEWS with news returns exactly the same results.

Comment: I was so confused that I was not changing the value of category_name to test the pagination for different categories. Now I confirmed that replacing NEWS with EVENTS does display the posts belonging to the latter category and clicking a pagination link does display correct posts.

Also, redefining $tag in 'tag_slug__and' => $tag enabled the tag archive page to display correct posts for each tag, but one thing though is clicking any of its pagination links or tag links returns the page not found error message...

Comment: Yes @EadWig, you're right about the slug, just in case your WP doesn't treat the `NEWS` and `news` as the same.. heh.. but (I think) it's a best practice to always use lowercase, unless of course the database value is not in all-lowercase..

Answer (score 1):

The tag template page began displaying posts for specific tags once I replaced the argument statement with the following, which is great!!:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag = $tags[0]->name;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'category_name' => 'NEWS',
    'tag_slug__and' => $tag,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

However, when I click on a pagination link on the tag archive page, Chrome returns 'This localhost page can’t be found'...

Comment: Actually, that error 404 is likely because of conflict with the main query on the category archive page. You'd need to tweak the `paginate_links()` `format`.

Comment: The pagination links seem to be showing correct pretty URLs such as /category/news/page/2. So as @SallyCJ pointed out, the cause of this problem is the way paginate_links() is set up? I can't spot any anomaly with the function...

Comment: When I said "conflict", I mean something like this: Let's say your category is `foo`, and the main query had 3 pages, while the custom query had 4 (or more) pages. So you visited `/category/foo/page/2` (the main query) and it worked well. Then you visited `/category/foo/page/4` (the custom query), but got the error `404`. Why? Because WordPress uses the main query with the requested URL and since the main query had only 3 pages of results, that's why the error `404` came up despite that you're actually navigating through the custom query's results.

Comment: And you could overcome the issue by tweaking the pagination links (their URL format) - use an "ugly" URL and use `my_paged` as the page number's key (the default is `paged`). But is it really necessary for you to make the custom query in the category template?? :) How about creating a standard Page (post type of `page`) and make your custom queries there (in a custom Page template)?